# Docker swarm tries to parse the value of ENV variable in my compose file (because it has a go template in it) and gives me an error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, go-templates, docker-swarm-mode

## The error

I try to launch a logspout container and set the log format (an ENV variable) via a docker-compose file. Not too difficult, and if I launch it with `docker-compose up`, everything works fine. But when I try to launch it with  docker `swarm init` and `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mystack`, I get an error:

*Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = expanding env failed: expanding env "RAW_FORMAT={ \"container\" : \"{{ .Container.Name }}\", \"labels\": {{ toJSON .Container.Config.Labels }}, \"timestamp\": \"{{ .Time.Format \"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00\" }}\", \"source\" : \"{{ .Source }}\", \"message\": {{ toJSON .Data }} }": template: expansion:1: function "toJSON" not defined*

## What I understand

I think I have the error only with swarm and not docker-compose, because the ENV variable I want to pass to logspout is:

*RAW_FORMAT: '{ "container" : "{{ .Container.Name }}", "labels": {{ toJSON .Container.Config.Labels }}, "timestamp": "{{ .Time.Format "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00" }}", "source" : "{{ .Source }}", "message": {{ toJSON .Data }} }'*

This ENV variable contains a go template. But with swarm mode, you can [create services using go-templates](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#create-services-using-templates). So it seems that swarm tries (and fails) to parse the value of the ENV variable that I just want to pass to the logspout container.

## My question

1. Is it a way to tell swarm not to parse the go-template in my RAW_FORMAT variable?
2. If not, is there an other way to set this variable to the correct value?

## More...

If you want to reproduce this problem, here is a minimal docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
logspout:
  image: gliderlabs/logspout:latest
  volumes:
    - /etc/hostname:/etc/host_hostname:ro
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  environment:
    RAW_FORMAT: '{ "container" : "{{ .Container.Name }}", "labels": {{ toJSON .Container.Config.Labels }}, "timestamp": "{{ .Time.Format "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00" }}", "source" : "{{ .Source }}", "message": {{ toJSON .Data }} }'
```

If you are on windows, you have to execute `$Env:COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1` first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In go templates, escaping `{{` can be done with `{{"{{"}}`, so your yml file should look like this:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  logspout:
    image: gliderlabs/logspout:latest
    volumes:
      - /etc/hostname:/etc/host_hostname:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      RAW_FORMAT: '{ "container" : "{{"{{"}} .Container.Name }}", "labels": {{"{{"}} toJSON .Container.Config.Labels }}, "timestamp": "{{"{{"}} .Time.Format "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00" }}", "source" : "{{"{{"}} .Source }}", "message": {{"{{"}} toJSON .Data }} }'
```

Comment: Hi Constantin. Thanks for your answer. With your solution I do not get the error in swarm, but sadly, logspout seems to escape "{{" too... So now, logs are not working ...

Comment: @OLIVIER how does the RAW_FORMAT looks like in the container?

Comment: @ CONSTANTIN after further testing, your solution seems to work. My bad. The logs were not working because in swarm mode, the .Container.Config.Labels contains .labels.com.docker.swarm.task wich, for some reason, causes a mapping error in elasticsearch. But this is a problem for another day (and maybe another post). Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can warp by `` {{` `` string `` `}} ``

```
  environment:
    RAW_FORMAT: '{{`{ "container" : "{{ .Container.Name }}`}}", "labels": {{ toJSON .Container.Config.Labels }}, "timestamp": "{{ .Time.Format "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00" }}", "source" : "{{ .Source }}", "message": {{ toJSON .Data }} }`}}'
```

Another example

```
LDAP_SEARCH_FILTER={{`(sAMAccountName={{username}})`}}
```