# Double-Double Curly Braces in docker-compose.yml for kafka

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I'm looking at wurstmeister/kafka-docker, and found this [pull](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/pull/377/commits/1966b1027e7f6d296b7a1e2b94d61c35316888b4) suggesting using the IP address.  Basically, it uses the docker info formatting:

```
HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "docker info -f '{{`{{.Swarm.NodeAddr}}`}}'"
```

I get the idea that it uses the formatting to get the address, but I don't understand what's going on with the extra {{...}}  and the backticks (which would normally be an eval).  docker-compose allows for ${variables}, but there's no dollar sign ($) here, so no need to escape.  Why isn't this just:

```
HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "docker info -f '{{.Swarm.NodeAddr}}'"
```

I've seen this elsewhere, so I assume there's a reason.

Comment: Removing kafka tag becuase it's not specific to Kafka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855230/docker-swarm-tries-to-parse-the-value-of-env-variable-in-my-compose-file-becaus).  However, you might not find that one if you aren't aware that docker-compose files use Go templates (I didn't find any mention of it in the [compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)).  So basically, in go,  the backquotes indicate a literal string, so the outer set of {{ }} is a template allowing for the backquotes to take everything between literally.